# How to create edit box in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, editbox

I'm new to Qt.

Just want to ask what should I use to create an edit box in Qt which will take single integer value?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reading Qt's documentation?

Comment: Watch some tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxlB34Cn0zw&index=3&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63 the same applies

Comment: Or this one if you want to read and follow steps: https://wiki.qt.io/Basic_Qt_Programming_Tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution:

```
QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0, 9, this);
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);

// the edit lineedit will only accept integers between 0 and 9
edit->setValidator(validator);
```

You can read more on Validator here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html and more on QLineEdit here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#details

Comment: For a newcomer to Qt I would suggest rather that he download the IDE and start with the designer. Although this is not an easy answer to give on SO